# Enable woocommerce payment gateway based on user = product author

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to enable the payment gateway 'cod' based on if the current user is the product author. Basically, when buying his own product, the user should have the additional payment gateway of cash, but obviously only for his own products. We use Dokan to create the vendor site.

My code so far:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);
function filter_gateways($gateways)
{
   global $woocommerce
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $users_product = false;
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
       $post_obj    = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
       $post_author = $post_obj->post_author;
       if ( is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID === $post_author ) $users_product = true;
   }
   if ( $users_product ! = true ) {

       unset($gateways['cod']);

   }
   return $gateways;
}
```

Anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting error or COD still displaying?

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few PHP syntax errors in your function. Try this instead.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);
function filter_gateways($gateways)
{
   global $woocommerce;
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $users_product = false;
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
       $post_obj    = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );
       $post_author = $post_obj->post_author;
       if ( is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post_author ) $users_product = true;
   }
   if ( $users_product != true ) {
       unset($gateways['cod']);
   }
   return $gateways;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. No more 500 error, but it's not showing the 'cod' gateway at all now, only other gateways... my guess is, it's always unsetting it now?

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I have accepted the answer and thank you again! Just a quick follow up, in the line where i check for if the current user id is == to the post author, is it possible to add an OR (||) statement to check against a value stored in my database? So if the meta_value of _vendor_id (thats the meta_key) equals the post author id, it would also be a true statement?

Comment: Basically my vendors can create staff, they have their own user id so the function above won't let them use 'cod' for the vendors products, but when the staff account is created, the vendors id is added to the staff account as _vendor_id meta. My thought is that we could check the meta value and if that is the same as the post author, they would also be able to use 'cod'

Comment: yeah, so checking for the logged in users meta value for meta_key -> _vendor_id. If that is the same as the value of the post_author, it should also be a true statement. Example: Post authors user id is 89, the staff user who has a different user id has the the meta value 89 for _vendor_staff, therefore should also be allowed to use the cod gateway

Comment: Try this `if ( is_user_logged_in() && ($current_user->ID == $post_author || get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_vendor_id', true) == $post_author)) $users_product = true;` and let me know.

Comment: What a hero! Amazing. Does exactly what it should, thank you.